# Building list of tuples from list in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, pattern-matching

I am trying to read content from a file and then organize it into a list of tuples. I have read the file into a list of numbers, however it seems to skip numbers immediately after newlines, how to prevent this behaviour?
I am guaranteed a file of even number of characters.

```
-module(brcp).
-export([parse_file/1]).

parse_file(Filename) ->
    read_file(Filename).

read_file(Filename) ->
    {ok, File} = file:read_file(Filename),
    Content = unicode:characters_to_list(File),
    build_tuples([begin {Int,_}=string:to_integer(Token), Int end|| Token<-string:tokens(Content," /n/r")]).

build_tuples(List) ->
    case List of 
        [] -> [];
        [E1,E2|Rest] -> [{E1,E2}] ++ build_tuples(Rest)
    end.
```

Here is a sample input file:

```
1 7 11 0
1 3 5 0 7 0
1 8 10 0 1 11
99 0
```

Comment: I think "list comprehensions" is a great start here, although you have only one list to start with and you need a list of tuples. In the mean time, I strongly believe it's "tuple" and not "touple"

Comment: Thanks :) I got the numbers alone read and loaded however if I encounter a newline it skips the number immediately following it D:

Comment: Can you add an example of the input data? I am convinced that using http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#split-2 will be more efficient here but can't suggest a solution without knowing what you are actually reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-module(tuples).
-export([parse/0]).

parse() ->
    {ok, File} = file:read_file("tuples.txt"),
    List = binary:split(File, [<<" ">>, <<"\t">>, <<"\n">>], [global, trim_all]),
    io:format("~p~n", [List]),
    build_tuples(List, []).

build_tuples([X,Y|T], Acc) ->
    build_tuples(T, [{X,Y}|Acc]);
build_tuples([X|T], Acc) ->
    build_tuples(T, [{X, undefined}|Acc]);
build_tuples([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

The text file I used is almost as yours but I added tabs and multiple spaces to make it more realistic:

```
1 7  11 0
1 3 5 0 7 0
    1 8 10   0 1 11
99  0
```

You can of course convert binaries to integers when adding them to tuples with [`erlang:binary_to_integer/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_integer-1). The [`binary:split/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#split-3) function used in the code parses all empty characters (tabs, spaces, new lines) to empty binaries and then `trim_all` ignores them. You can skip them if your input is always well-formed. Result:

```
14> tuples:parse().
[<<"1">>,<<"7">>,<<"11">>,<<"0">>,<<"1">>,<<"3">>,<<"5">>,<<"0">>,<<"7">>,<<"0">>,<<"1">>,<<"8">>,<<"10">>,<<"0">>,<<"1">>,<<"11">>,<<"99">>,<<"0">>]
[{<<"1">>,<<"7">>},{<<"11">>,<<"0">>},{<<"1">>,<<"3">>},{<<"5">>,<<"0">>},{<<"7">>,<<"0">>},{<<"1">>,<<"8">>},{<<"10">>,<<"0">>},{<<"1">>,<<"11">>},{<<"99">>,<<"0">>}]
```

Comment: Hahahahha, the token delimeters I was using were using a forward slash instead of a backslash, it works as I want it now!